# error: cannot convert from'func::str' to 'str*'

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm getting this error but I really don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
static struct str* func(void);
int main(void) {

   return 0;
}
static struct  str* func(void) {
   struct str {
       char arimb1 : 4;
       char arimb2 : 4;
       char arimb3 : 4;
       char arimb4 : 4;
   }s;
   static struct  str * ptr;
   ptr = &s;
   return (ptr);

}
```

And the error(s) are:

```
return value type does not match the function type  [E0120]
'return': cannot convert from 'func::str *' to 'str *' [C2440]
```

Thank you all so much!
PS: I'm using Visual Studio (Microsoft) but I've tried also repl c and I'm getting the same error there too.

Comment: Hi all, anyway. Sorry if my english isn't really good.

Comment: You're trying to return a  pointer to a local variable. That's not valid because the variable is destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: You should make `s` static, not `ptr`.

Comment: returning a pointer to variable that declared in function scope or stack frame (which will be released by the os after the return qualifier). is dissaster and an action that shouldnt be done! the pointer declared as a static but he points to non static variable!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that you're declaring the structure within the function. The structure declaration should be outside the function, so that the type `struct str` is the same in both scopes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct str {
    char arimb1 : 4;
    char arimb2 : 4;
    char arimb3 : 4;
    char arimb4 : 4;
};
static struct str* func(void);

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}

static struct  str* func(void) {
    static struct str s;
    struct str *ptr;
    ptr = &s;
    return (ptr);
}
```

Also, to avoid returning a pointer to an automatic variable, you should declare `s` to be `static`. There's no need to make `ptr` static.

Comment: I thank you all very very  much. Now I know why the errors were generated.